# Chrome navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia FAILURE

Tags: google-chrome, webcam

I am developing a Chrome extension and I am having trouble with accessing/using the USB connected web cam using `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia`.

I just get a empty video element in Chrome. The same `camera.html` (which is served over `HTTPS`) works in FireFox and I can see the intended feed.

Incidentally, with the same setup/code, it all works well with my internal web cam in both Chrome and FireFox .

CHROME VERSION:Version 78.0.3904.108 (Official Build) (64-bit)
OS : Windows 8.1 (64 Bit)

I poured over many articles/posts on web but none has any solution.Some, even suggests its is an issue with CHROME.

Here is the code of camera.html:
***HTML***

```
<video id="videoElement" autoplay />
```

***javascript***

```
var video = document.querySelector("#videoElement");
if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
    console.log('navigator.mediaDevices.....');
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({  video: true })
    .then(function(stream) {
          console.log('got the stream............');
          video.srcObject = stream;
          window.localStream = stream;

     })
     .catch(function(e) { console.log(e); });
} else ...
```

In CHROME i  get to the console log 'navigator.mediaDevices...' *BUT NOTHING AFTER THAT.*
Neither 'got the stream...' log NOR any error from catch.

WHATS WRONG ? NEED help !!

Answer (score 0):

You can have a Chrome related issue, I had the same problem with embedded camera on win 10,  and I fixed it by using Search (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) 'Microphone privacy settings'.

The following link suggest a couple of aspects: https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/2062037